# Präpositionen bei Jahres-/Monatsangaben (aus/vom/von Januar)

Tags: preposition, time

Ich habe nach Erscheinungsjahr/-monat/-tag gruppierte Listen von Zeitungsartikeln und suche möglichst kurze Überschriften dafür.

Ich bin mir unsicher, welche Präpositionen ich verwenden soll.

#### Jahr

Heißt es »aus« oder »von«? Oder ganz anders?

> Artikel **aus** 2015
>   Artikel **von** 2015

#### Monat und Jahr

Heißt es »aus«, »vom« oder »von«? Oder ganz anders?

> Artikel **aus** Januar 2015
>   Artikel **vom** Januar 2015
>   Artikel **von** Januar 2015

#### Tag, Monat und Jahr

Hier fällt mir nur »vom« ein. Oder gibt es noch andere Möglichkeiten?

> Artikel **vom** 17. Januar 2015

Answer (score 1):

Ausgehend von der Formulierung in ganzen Sätzen, stammen Artikel …

> … aus dem Jahr 2015
>   … vom Januar 2015
>   … vom 17. Januar 2015

Ein Artikel stammt ferner …

> … aus der Zeitschrift XY 
>   … vom Autor XY

ein Buch

> … vom Verlag XY

Nur umgangssprachlich sagt man auch: dieser Artikel **ist** …

> … von 2015,

aber man schreibt deswegen trotzdem **nicht:** "die Artikel von 2015 sind nicht mehr so gut wie die von 2014".

Für knappe Überschriften sind diese Formulierungen wohl zu lang. Man kann jetzt nicht einfach das "Jahr" herauskürzen (man kann natürlich, nur klingt und ist es falsch), z. B. "aus 2015". "Aus" ist eine Präposition, die die geografische Herkunft angibt, jemand könnte "2015" mit einer Postleitzahl verwechseln. "Von" weist auf eine Urheberschaft oder einen Eigentümer hin, "von 2015" könnte theoretisch als Angabe eines Autoren-Pseudonyms oder eines Verlages aufgefasst werden (den Verlag 2001 gibt es ja beispielsweise). Als Überschrift möglich wäre:

> "2015 publizierte Artikel:" oder
>   "Seit (Datum) publizierte Artikel:" oder
>   "Publikationen des Jahres 2015:"

und in dieser Rubrik nachfolgend als Überschriften jeweils nur Monat oder Datum.

> "Artikel vom 17. Januar 2015:"

ist z. B. völlig korrekt.

Es hängt wohl auch davon ab, ob hier Artikel nach Erscheinungsjahr, -monat und -tag sortiert werden sollen oder z.áB. die Publikationen eines Jahres nach Textsorten (Artikel, Buchtitel etc.). Man könnte dann jeweils die übergeordnete Kategorie voransetzen (z. B. "Publikationen 2015") und die untergeordneten nur nach dem benennen, was jeweils unterschiedlich ist (Textsorte, Jahr, Monat etc.).

Comment: Die Behauptungen in dieser Antwort sind m.E. zum Teil unzutreffend. Was an _Die Artikel von 2015 sind nicht mehr so gut wie die von 2014_ falsch sein soll, erschließt sich etwa nicht. Auch die Behauptung, _aus_ + Jahreszahl passe in zeitbezogenen Kontexten nicht, überzeugt nicht. Dies wird etwa am juristischen Sprachgebrauch deutlich, wo das Jahr in Aktenzeichen stets so gesprochen wird ("III ZR 4/19" ist "drei ZR vier **aus** neunzehn/zwanzig-neunzehn/zwo-neunzehn"). ... (1/2)

Comment: ... Auch einschlägige Korpora enthalten viele Beispiele. Hier nur einige aus dem Spiegel: _Der Vorgang aus 1994 war 1999 ... verjährt._ (Spiegel, 17.01.2000) / _... kassierten sie folglich die Boni aus 2000 ..._ (Spiegel, 08.08.2005) / _Ergebnisse aus 2006_ (Spiegel, 23.06.2008) / _... fordert Pinkwart nun drei Millionen Euro aus 2007 zurück ..._ (Spiegel, 29.12.2008) / _... überstiegen den Umsatz aus 2008 ..._ (Spiegel, 17.05.2010). (2/2)

Answer (score 0):

Erlaubt mir, die Sache zu verwirren:

> Die im Jahr 2015 erschienenen Artikel waren qualitativ besser als die aus dem Jahr 2014.

Also kommt noch 'im' ins Rennen.

Man kann sich über die Frage nach dem Zeitraum an die Fragestellung des Beitrags herantasten:

> "An welchem Tag ist der Artikel erschienen?" – "Der Artikel ist vom 01.08.2014."

'An' als Fragewort wird ebenfalls für Orte verwendet, womit 'vom' in der Antwort richtig ist. 
Dies gilt auch, wenn man es so formuliert:

> "Aus welchem Zeitraum stammt der Artikel?" – "Der Artikel ist vom August 2014."

Die Art der Fragestellung kann hier aber wertend verstanden werden. Die Frage nach der Abstammung ist ebenfalls enthalten. Damit ist hier das Umfeld gemeint, in der der Artikel geschrieben wurde. Die Antwort könnte auch lauten: "Der Artikel stammt aus der Zeit, als Erdogan zum Präsidenten der Türkei gewählt wurde."

Man kann die Frage jedoch geringfügig abändern.

> "In welchem Zeitraum ist der Artikel erschienen?" – "Der Artikel ist aus {dem Zeitraum} August 2014."

Die Frage wird mit "in" eingeleitet, also muss es hier "aus" heißen. Es wird explizit nach einem Datum gefragt. Die Frage lässt keine Wertung zu. Die Verwendung von "aus" ist formaler. Im Zweifel 'Erscheinungsjahr 20xy' als Überschrift wählen.

Comment: Das scheint eine Antwort auf eine andere Antwort, nicht auf die Frage zu sein. So funktioniert das hier aber nicht.

Comment: @Carsten S vielen Dank für den Hinweis.
War die Frage nicht, unter welchen Umständen man 'aus', 'von' oder 'vom' wählt?

Answer (score 0):

Alle Varianten sind ungefähr gleich gut, denke ich. Welche du nimmst, würde ich abhängig machen von:

1. Form (schreibst du eine Tabelle?)
2. Kontext (akademisch? Journalismus?)
3. eigene Vorliebe

Auch möglich sind ggf.:

> Titel (2015)
>
> Titel (01.01.2015)
>
> der 2015er Artikel

Letzteres ist wahrscheinlich nicht so angemessen.